# Ajax + browser backbutton = checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I have a content page which is loaded via Ajax with a checkbox on it. The checkboxes works as it should when I click the normal menu buttons on my webpage to get to the content. But when I go to another page and use the back button to get back to the page which has the checkboxes, the checkboxes stop working.

html:

```
<div id="filters">
    <ul id="filters-background">
        <li id="option-type">Filter Options</li>
        <li class="wave2"><label for="white">White<input type="checkbox" name="white" value=".White" id="white"></label></li>
        <li class="wave2"><label for="blue">Blue<input type="checkbox" name="blue" value=".Blue" id="blue"></label></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    OnSort();
</script>
```

js:

```
function OnSort(e) {
    console.log('aaa');

    // filter button click
    var filterCheckboxes = $('#filters input');
    var filters = [];
    filterCheckboxes.change(function() {
        console.log('clicked checkbox');

        filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
            console.log('working');
            filters.push( this.value );
        });
    });
}
```

If you look at the above code, the console will output 'aaa' when I click on the back button but if I test a checkbox it will not output 'clicked checkbox' in the console. How can I make it so the checkboxes will keep working even after I use the browser back button?

Maybe relevant PageLoad and Backbutton Ajax code:

```
function OnLoadPage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageurl = $(this).data('url');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: pageurl,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data['content']); // update content

            if(data['menu']) { // update menu
                $('#menu').html(data['menu']);
            }
            else {
                $('#menu').html('');
            }

            // update url
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl}, '', pageurl);
        },
        error: function(response) {
           alert('ERROR:' + response.responseText);
        }
    });
}

function InitOverrideBrowserBackButton() {
    // override the back button to get the ajax content without page reload
    $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
        $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab', success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data['content']); // update content

            if(data['menu']) { // update menu
                $('#menu').html(data['menu']);
            }
            else {
                $('#menu').html('');
            }
        }});
    });
}
```

I've also tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '#filters input', function() {
    console.log('clicked checkbox');

    filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
        console.log('working');
        filters.push( this.value );
    });
});
```

Which will output 'aaa' and 'clicked checkbox' but not 'working'.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with help from others on StackOverflow. Here's the answer:

```
function OnSort(e) {
    console.log('aaa');

    // filter button click
    var filters = [];
    $(document).on('click', '#filters input', function() {
        console.log('clicked checkbox');

        $('#filters input', document).filter(':checked').each(function() {
            console.log('working');
            filters.push( this.value );
        });
    });
}
```